# How do you include a field.tpl.php, to a custom views field handler. outside of the theme?

Tags: views

so i've created my custom field handler in views. and i want to include a field template in the module. i can achieve what i need by copying the views-view-field.tpl.php into my theme. but i want views-view-field--MYMODULE.tpl.php to be scanned and used from the module folder..

do i need to "declare a theme function" in my

class views_handler_MYMODULE extends views_handler_field

THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding a field template to the templates folder of your module won't work because, by default views doesn't utilize field templates. However you can explicitly set a template file using the _theme function in your module ie:

```
function MODULE_NAME_theme($existing) {
  return array(
    'views_view_field__FIELD_NAME' => array(
      'arguments' => array('view' => NULL, 'field' => NULL, 'row' => NULL),
      'template' => 'views-view-field--FIELD-NAME',
      'original hook' => 'views_view_field',
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULE_NAME') . '/templates',
    ),
  );
}
```

Source: http://grayside.org/2010/09/how-override-views-field-template-module

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a template file being loaded from your module's templates folder, you should do the following:

1. Implement hook_views_api to tell Views where you keep views templates, e.g. `your_module/templates`
2. Following the naming conventions for Views and add views-view-field.tpl.php into your module's template folder, e.g. `your_module/templates`

After you clear your cache and rescan the template folders using Views UI, your tpl file should be selected.

Hope this helps, the main source for this answer was https://stevenyeung.com/article/template-override-drupal-views-3-from-module/